# File upload is not working in my Cypress.io test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing for File upload, which is not working in my Cypress.io test, after refreshing the site, I can't see the 'avatar.JPG' ( *which is under ../fixtures/avatar.JPG* ) is not getting attached. I am calling the uploadFile() in my test which is written in commands.js file. Someone please advise what could be the underlying problem here.

```
cy.get('.qq-upload-button span').contains("Upload New File").click({force: true})
    const fileName = '../fixtures/avatar.JPG';
    const fileType = 'JPG|JPEG|PNG';
    const fileInput = 'input[type=file]';
    cy.uploadFile(fileName, fileType, fileInput);
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get("#save-edit-button").click()
```

../support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', (fileName, fileType = ' ', selector) => {
    cy.get('.qq-upload-button span').contains("Upload New File").then(subject => {
      cy.fixture("avatar.JPG", 'base64')
        .then(Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob)
        .then(blob => {
          const el = subject[0]
          const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, { type: fileType })
          const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
          dataTransfer.items.add(testFile)
          el.files = dataTransfer.files
        })
    })
  })
```